# Why the proof of Catalan's conjecture is not easily generalizable?

Tags: diophantine-equations, open-problem

Let $x,y>0$, $u,v>1$ be integers. Why is it easier to solve $x^u-y^v=1$ than $x^u-y^v=2$? Is there possible some group behind the first equation which has some nice property that the group made by the second equation has not?

Comment: Why is it easier to solve $x^2+y^2=z^2$ than $x^n+y^n=z^n$ ($n>2$)?

Comment: This already has an answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167940/can-we-extend-the-proof-of-catalans-conjecture).

Comment: Catalan's conjecture was only proven with the help of massive computation effort, maybe difference $2$ needs even more computations.